# Can a WPF Style be used to apply currency formatting to a DataGrid cell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've got a WPF DataGrid and wish to apply a currency format to several of the columns. I can do this on a per-column basis using `Binding={Binding FieldName, StringFormat={}{0:C}`, but I'd prefer to define the currency format once - presumably in a `<Style>` resource - and just apply that resource to each column that needs formatting.

Problem is, I've no idea how to set a Binding's StringFormat property from within a style. Is it possible to set that or a similar property in a `<Style>`, or am I barking up the wrong tree with this approach?

**Update:** I've successfully applied a style to the cells in my DataGridTextColumn, and setting the `ContentStringFormat` property of the cell seems like it'd be the way to go... but whatever value I put in there seems to get ignored.

Comment: If you are going to be applying the style on a per-column basis, what is wrong with applying the StringFormat instead? I would think that it would be easier to read if done in the binding instead of in a style.

Comment: Possibly more readable, yes. But I'm thinking in terms of extension: let's say in the future I want all currency columns formatted such that their text colour changes to red when they contain negative amounts (as commonly seen on financial preadsheets). That's the sort of common behavior I'd want encapsulated in a style; and I'd hate to have the colour formatting and the currency formatting in different places...

Comment: In reference to the negative value I would bind the ForeColor of the cell to the value and use a Converter, returning Red for a negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Template for a DataGrid cell, and use the `{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}` value for the converter parameter.

I haven't tested this code, but something like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="CurrencyFormatCell">
    <TextBlock 
        Text="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content, Converter={StaticResource FormatCurrencyConverter}}"
        ForeGround="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyTextColorConverter}}"
        />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry this took so long to accept - it's taken me a while to come back around to this. In order to encapsulate everything that's been mentioned I probably *would* end up going with a cell template, rather than a style. Thanks!